# How do I create an h1 element for each value of an array?

Tags: javascript, html

Hypothetically, say I have an array named "fruits" which included different fruits.
Something that looks like this:

```js
var fruits = ["bannanna", "apple", "orange", "grapes"]
```

I want to create an h1 element with each of of the names in the array. How do I do this?

Comment: Where do you want to put the h1 elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the items, and use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to add the item to the body or where ever you want to add it.

```js
var fruits = ["bannanna", "apple", "orange", "grapes"]

fruits.forEach(item => document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<h1>${item}</h1>`))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by through forEach.

```
<div id="generate-h1"></div>

var fruits = ["bannanna", "apple", "orange", "grapes"]

// Create any HTML Element to put H1 Tags into this HTML Tag
var main = document.createElement('main');

// Create H1 items for each fruits
// Append it to the main Tag or whatever you have.
fruits.forEach(function (fruits) {
    var headline = document.createElement('h1');
    headline.textContent = fruits;
    main.appendChild(headline);
});


// Inject into the DOM
var app = document.querySelector('#generate-h1');
app.appendChild(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay try this I am sure this will work:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Try This</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="fruit"></h1>
    <script>
      var fruits = ["bannanna", "apple", "orange", "grapes"];
      var text = "";
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
        text += fruits[i] + "<br>";
      }
      document.getElementById("fruit").innerHTML = text;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```